# Check URL change in WebView

Tags: java, android, url

This function is not working when I change URL and go to another page in WebView.

Here is the code:

```
@Deprecated
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Url Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String url = view.getUrl();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please format your code so it‘s easier to read it?

Answer (score 0):

from android lolipop, there is a new method. so you have to use the two methods

```
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                         @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                 Toast.makeText(this, "Url Change",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 String url = view.getUrl();
                            }


                            return true;
                        }

                         @Override
                         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                           Toast.makeText(this, "Url Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             String url = view.getUrl();
                             return true;
                        }
                    });

 });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

as well, make sure you set

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

like the above code.

Happy Code!

Comment: thanks for helping me but I already do using shouldInterceptRequest method